# Complex Number $(a + bi)$ to Simplest Radical Form

Tags: complex-numbers, radicals, calculator

I have a number in a + bi form, the number is $25 \pm   48.73397172i$.
I desperately need to find a way to get this number into simplest radical form. I am trying to write a program for a TI-83+ calculator that allows me to take a quadratic formula problem (the sample I am using is $5p^2  - 10p + 24 = 0$).
I can get it into $a + bi$ form using a simple quadratic formula program I wrote a while back, but I just can't seem to figure out how to turn it into simplest radical form. Any help is appreciated whether it's help with a calculator program or with turning my $a + bi$ solution into a simplest radical form.

P.S. Simplest radical form should be $\dfrac{5 \pm i\sqrt{95}} {5}$

Comment: I find very confusing this question: the imaginary part is close to $\;\sqrt{2,375}\;$, but why do you think the "radical form", whatever that is, of the given complex number is the number you wrote up there is something I can't understand...

Answer (score 1):

$25 \pm 48.73397172i\approx 5 (5 \pm i\sqrt{95})$, not $\frac{5 \pm i\sqrt{95}}5$.

As DonAntonio did, square $48.73397172$ and you get a value very close to $2375$. (The square root of an integer is either an integer itself or is irrational. Since $\sqrt{2375}$ is obviously not integer, it is irrational. And because it is irrational, it cannot be expressed in any finite number of digits. Thus your $48.73397172$ is only an approximation of the actual square root.)

So your values are actually $25 \pm \sqrt{2375}i$. But the square root can be reduced. Factor $2375 = 5^3\cdot19$, so $\sqrt{2375} = \sqrt{5^2}\sqrt{5\cdot19} = 5\sqrt{95}$.

So your values can be expressed as $25 \pm 5\sqrt{95}i$. But there is a common multiple of 5 between the terms, which can be factored out, leaving them as

$$5 (5 \pm i\sqrt{95})$$

Comment: Thanks, this has helped immensely. One thing I'm still hung up on is where my b part came from. I know that 48.73397172 squared is 2375, but in order to finish my program I need to know where I'm getting that from. I also know that the 95 I have multiplied by my twenty five is 2375. How do I get to 2375 or preferably 48.73397172 from my original problem which is the 5p squared - 10p + 24 = 0

Comment: The solutions of $5p^2 - 10p +24 = 0$ can be found by applying the quadratic formula: $$p = \frac{-(-10) \pm \sqrt{(-10)^2 - 4\cdot 5\cdot 24}}{2\cdot 5}  = \frac{10 \pm \sqrt{-380}}{10} = \frac{5 \pm i\sqrt{95}}5$$ How you ended up with those values multiplied by 25, I don't know. Likely it was some math error.